# how to make apache rewrite this url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/directory1/directory2/cgi-bin/something.cgi/http/www.hello.com
```

into

```
www.mysite.com/directory1/directory2/something/www.hello.com
```

OR

```
www.mysite.com/www.hello.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think you want to rewrite the other direction:

```
RewriteRule ^www\.[^/]+$ directory1/directory2/cgi-bin/something.cgi/http/$0
```